# Stopwatch not incrementing

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

I don't understand why this code fails to measure when 4 hours has elapsed.

```
    if (guildVaultRunStarter.IsRunning)
    {
        if (guildVaultRunTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 4 hours
        {
            guildVaultRunStarter.Reset();
            log("Its been over 4 hours - empty bags.");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            log("guildVaultRunTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds = " +
                guildVaultRunTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + ".");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        log("Start the 4 hour guild vault countdown.");
        guildVaultRunStarter.Reset();
        guildVaultRunStarter.Start();
    }
```

The logging shows this:

```
[8/23/2009 12:17:21 PM]:Start the 4 hour guild vault countdown.
...
[8/23/2009 12:26:53 PM]:guildVaultRunTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds = 0.
...
[8/23/2009 12:27:26 PM]:guildVaultRunTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds = 0.
```

Why is it always 0?

Comment: Always add the language to tags while asking a question with sample codes. It will provide you a better audience :)

Answer (score 5):

Is it just a typo between `guildVaultRunTimer` and `guildVaultRunStarter`?

i.e.

```
if (guildVaultRunStarter.ElapsedMilliseconds > ...
```

You never seem to start `guildVaultRunTimer`, after all.

Comment: /me shudders in shock and swears to never have such similar variable names again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you instantiate the timer and where/how is this bit of code called?

Comment: When the class is started I have:
private Stopwatch guildVaultRunStarter = new Stopwatch();

The code is called when the character kills a mob and loots an item.  Bags fill in 5 hours so the idea is to empty them in 4.